# Oracle queries getting stuck intermittently

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are having datawarehouse set-up where Informatica is used as ETL tool, Oracle 12c as database and various reporting tools. For reporting, we use queries to get staging data. These queries are run by informatica and extracts millions of record. Some queries are very simple such as -

```
select * from table A
```

Problem we are facing is, some of these queries run fine for sometime fetches few millions of records and get stuck. Event shown at oracle is always-

```
SQL*Net more data to client
```

so does that mean problem lies with Informatica. Does it become unresponsive after consuming large data? Is there a limit for Infomatica on consumption of rows from oracle cause some of these queries run simultaneously.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

> so does that mean problem lies with Informatica?

Yes may be. This wait event also indicate network bottleneck.

Check:

the time in the client process(in your case Informatica)

the time in the network between the client and the server.

arraysize for every fetch call.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience I have seen this when there is connection problem meaning Informatica Server is not able to connect to DB server or latency issue.

Per Oracle Documentation
(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16240_01/doc/doc.102/e16282/oracle_database_help/oracle_database_wait_bottlenecks_net_more_from_client_pct.html) these are primary areas to look into,

Network latency problems
tcp_no_delay configuration issues
Large array insert
Soft parsing, shipping SQL and PL/SQL text. 
Using stored procedures and packages will help alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get an AWR report for the offending period. You may find that the Informatica server may be maxed out, while the database is "twiddling it's thumbs"